# How to manage pop-up using Selenium Web Driver in github

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup, webdriver

I'm having troubles with managing of the pop-up in the github.
Test case which I'd like to automate is:
1. Go to https://github.com/YOUR_USER/YOUR_REPO/settings
2. Click "Delete Repository" button (pop-up appears)
3. Fill in the name of your repository into the input in pop-up
4. Click "I understand the consequences, delete this repository" the button in pop-up

I don't know how to find the element in pop-up in the 3d step.
When I'm just tryin' to do this, webdriver fails to find element

```
driver.findElement(By.name("verify")).sendKeys(repoName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following locator (css selector) should work:

```
#facebox .input-block"
```

Use this locator as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#facebox .input-block")).sendKeys(repoName);
```

Another css selector that you can use is as follows:

```
#facebox [name=verify]

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#facebox [name=verify]")).sendKeys(repoName);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more that one `input` tags with the same `name` attribute value "verify". You need to select the second one and not the first. You can try something like this:

```
driver.findElements(By.name("verify"))[1].sendKeys(repoName);
```